# Cannot Deploy WAR file correctly on WASCE 3.0

Tags: java, maven, war

Trying to migrate from WASCE 2.1.1.4 to WASCE 3.0. I am using the WASCE Console Manager 'Deployer' option to deploy the WAR and it seems to work ok, however, it is not unpacking the WAR in the deployment directory like it did in 2.1.1.4 and subsequently the Web App will not start and throws the following errors:

```
`2014-01-02 21:59:17,501 WARN  [PersistentPermissionResolver] no permission store available - please install a PermissionStore with the name` 'org.jboss.seam.security.jpaPermissionStore' if persistent permissions are required.

2014-01-02 21:59:20,313 ERROR [[/MyWebProject]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener
org.jboss.seam.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate Seam component: repositoryConfiguration
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2170)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:304)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.startup(Contexts.java:278)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.ServletLifecycle.endInitialization(ServletLifecycle.java:143)
    at org.jboss.seam.init.Initialization.init(Initialization.java:744)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.contextInitialized(SeamListener.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext.access$201(GeronimoStandardContext.java:121)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext$SystemMethodValve.invoke(GeronimoStandardContext.java:723)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.invoke(GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.java:48)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.ProtectedTargetValve.invoke(ProtectedTargetValve.java:53)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext.startInternal(GeronimoStandardContext.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatContainer.addContext(TomcatContainer.java:310)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatWebAppContext.doStart(TomcatWebAppContext.java:567)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.createInstance(GBeanInstance.java:1000)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:271)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.start(GBeanInstance.java:555)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.attemptFullStart(GBeanDependency.java:110)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.addTarget(GBeanDependency.java:145)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency$1.running(GBeanDependency.java:119)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:176)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.access$300(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:45)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor$RawLifecycleBroadcaster.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:254)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:301)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.startRecursive(GBeanInstanceState.java:127)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.startRecursive(GBeanInstance.java:569)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.startRecursiveGBean(BasicKernel.java:386)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.ConfigurationUtil.startConfigurationGBeans(ConfigurationUtil.java:466)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.KernelConfigurationManager.start(KernelConfigurationManager.java:225)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:710)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:689)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.plugin.local.StartCommand.run(StartCommand.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: exception invoking: create
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:154)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2275)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callCreateMethod(Component.java:2198)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2158)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56)
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.RollbackInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RollbackInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.MethodContextInterceptor.aroundInvoke(MethodContextInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.interceptInvocation(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.JavaBeanInterceptor.invoke(JavaBeanInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.repository.RepositoryStartupService_$$_javassist_seam_2.create(RepositoryStartupService_$$_javassist_seam_2.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22)
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOExceptionWithCause
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.util.BundleWriter.writeName(BundleWriter.java:446)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.util.BundleWriter.writeBundle(BundleWriter.java:91)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.util.BundleBinding.writeBundle(BundleBinding.java:164)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.BundleDbPersistenceManager.storeBundle(BundleDbPersistenceManager.java:1078)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.putBundle(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.java:684)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.storeInternal(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.java:626)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.store(AbstractBundlePersistenceManager.java:503)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.BundleDbPersistenceManager.store(BundleDbPersistenceManager.java:479)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.version.InternalVersionManagerImpl.<init>(InternalVersionManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.createVersionManager(RepositoryImpl.java:509)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.<init>(RepositoryImpl.java:329)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.create(RepositoryImpl.java:605)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository$2.getRepository(TransientRepository.java:232)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository.startRepository(TransientRepository.java:280)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.TransientRepository.login(TransientRepository.java:376)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.AbstractRepository.login(AbstractRepository.java:123)
    at org.drools.repository.JCRRepositoryConfigurator.login(JCRRepositoryConfigurator.java:95)
    at org.drools.repository.RulesRepositoryConfigurator.login(RulesRepositoryConfigurator.java:85)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.repository.RepositoryStartupService.newSession(RepositoryStartupService.java:213)
    at org.drools.guvnor.server.repository.RepositoryStartupService.create(RepositoryStartupService.java:97)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.IOExceptionWithCause
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.apache.geronimo.hook.equinox.GeronimoClassLoader.loadClass(GeronimoClassLoader.java:85)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 83 more
2014-01-02 21:59:20,313 ERROR [StandardContext] Error listenerStart
2014-01-02 21:59:20,313 ERROR [StandardContext] Context [/MyWebProject] startup failed due to previous errors
2014-01-02 21:59:20,313 ERROR [ContainerBase] ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[0.0.0.0].StandardContext[/MyWebProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatContainer.addContext(TomcatContainer.java:310)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatWebAppContext.doStart(TomcatWebAppContext.java:567)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.createInstance(GBeanInstance.java:1000)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:271)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.start(GBeanInstance.java:555)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.attemptFullStart(GBeanDependency.java:110)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.addTarget(GBeanDependency.java:145)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency$1.running(GBeanDependency.java:119)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:176)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.access$300(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:45)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor$RawLifecycleBroadcaster.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:254)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:301)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.startRecursive(GBeanInstanceState.java:127)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.startRecursive(GBeanInstance.java:569)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.startRecursiveGBean(BasicKernel.java:386)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.ConfigurationUtil.startConfigurationGBeans(ConfigurationUtil.java:466)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.KernelConfigurationManager.start(KernelConfigurationManager.java:225)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:710)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:689)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.plugin.local.StartCommand.run(StartCommand.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.io.IOException: Context did not start for an unknown reason
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext.startInternal(GeronimoStandardContext.java:473)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Context did not start for an unknown reason
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext$SystemMethodValve.invoke(GeronimoStandardContext.java:728)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.invoke(GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.java:48)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.ProtectedTargetValve.invoke(ProtectedTargetValve.java:53)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext.startInternal(GeronimoStandardContext.java:459)
    ... 27 more
Removing all listeners...
Listeners removed...
2014-01-02 21:59:20,329 WARN  [TomcatWebAppContext] TomcatWebAppContext failed
2014-01-02 21:59:20,329 ERROR [GBeanInstanceState] Error while starting; GBean is now in the FAILED state: abstractName="default/MyWebProject/1.0/war?J2EEApplication=null,j2eeType=WebModule,name=default/MyWebProject/1.0/war"
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[0.0.0.0].StandardContext[/MyWebProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatContainer.addContext(TomcatContainer.java:310)
    at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.TomcatWebAppContext.doStart(TomcatWebAppContext.java:567)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.createInstance(GBeanInstance.java:1000)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:271)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.start(GBeanInstance.java:555)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.attemptFullStart(GBeanDependency.java:110)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency.addTarget(GBeanDependency.java:145)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanDependency$1.running(GBeanDependency.java:119)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:176)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor.access$300(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:45)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicLifecycleMonitor$RawLifecycleBroadcaster.fireRunningEvent(BasicLifecycleMonitor.java:254)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.attemptFullStart(GBeanInstanceState.java:301)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.start(GBeanInstanceState.java:105)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstanceState.startRecursive(GBeanInstanceState.java:127)
    at org.apache.geronimo.gbean.runtime.GBeanInstance.startRecursive(GBeanInstance.java:569)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.basic.BasicKernel.startRecursiveGBean(BasicKernel.java:386)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.ConfigurationUtil.startConfigurationGBeans(ConfigurationUtil.java:466)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.KernelConfigurationManager.start(KernelConfigurationManager.java:225)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:710)
    at org.apache.geronimo.kernel.config.SimpleConfigurationManager.startConfiguration(SimpleConfigurationManager.java:689)
    at org.apache.geronimo.deployment.plugin.local.StartCommand.run(StartCommand.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is what my deployment plan looks like in 'geronimo-web.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<web:web-app xmlns:app="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/application-2.0" xmlns:bp="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" xmlns:client="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/application-client-2.0" xmlns:conn="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/connector-1.2" xmlns:dep="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/deployment-1.2" xmlns:ejb="http://openejb.apache.org/xml/ns/openejb-jar-2.2" xmlns:jaspi="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/geronimo-jaspi" xmlns:log="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/loginconfig-2.0" xmlns:name="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/naming-1.2" xmlns:pers="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:pkgen="http://openejb.apache.org/xml/ns/pkgen-2.1" xmlns:sec="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/security-2.0" xmlns:web="http://geronimo.apache.org/xml/ns/j2ee/web-2.0.1">
    <dep:environment>
        <dep:moduleId>
            <dep:groupId>default</dep:groupId>
            <dep:artifactId>MyWebProject</dep:artifactId>
            <dep:version>1.0</dep:version>
            <dep:type>war</dep:type>
        </dep:moduleId>
        <dep:hidden-classes>
            <dep:filter>com.thoughtworks.xstream.</dep:filter>
        </dep:hidden-classes>
    </dep:environment>
    <web:context-root>/MyWebProject</web:context-root>
</web:web-app>
```

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks